# Angular 2 - Setting Dialog - Can't resolve all parameters for SettingsComponent

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to create a dialog box for my application settings. I have created a new settings component with following code ( reference from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) ).

`settings.component.html`:

```html
<md-dialog-title>Settings</md-dialog-title>
<div md-dialog-content>
  <md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="data.theme">Toggle Theme</md-slide-toggle>
</div>
<div md-dialog-actions>
  <button md-button [md-dialog-close]="data.theme" tabindex="2">Save</button>
  <button md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

`settings.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from "@angular/material"
@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.css']
})
export class SettingsComponent{
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<SettingsComponent>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Referring this code from `main-nav.componenet.html`:

```html
<button md-menu-item (click)="openDialog()"><md-icon>settings</md-icon>Settings</button>
```

`main-nav.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogConfig, MdSidenav} from "@angular/material";
import {SettingsComponent} from "../settings/settings.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-nav',
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-nav.component.css']
})
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  private sideNavRef: MdSidenav;

  @Output()
  private colorRef: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  private isDarkTheme = false;
  theme: boolean;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeTheme(){
    this.isDarkTheme = !this.isDarkTheme;
    this.colorRef.emit(this.isDarkTheme);
    console.log(this.isDarkTheme);
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SettingsComponent, <MdDialogConfig>{
      width: '250px',
      data: {theme: this.isDarkTheme}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      // this.isDarkTheme=result;
    })
}

}
```

The application is compiling fine but I am unable to run it. getting the following exception:

> ERROR in C:/my-data/code/xenia/xenia-ui/src/app/settings/settings.component.ts (2,22): Module '"C:/my-data/code/xenia/xenia-ui/node_modules/@angular/material/index"' has no exported member 'MD_DIALOG_DATA'.

Comment: Did you get the latest material2?

Comment: @Edric - thanks issue has been resolved with latest angular material2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation with MAT_DIALOG_DATA and the problem was that I didn't have my component set as an entry component for the app.

In your app.module.ts add the following:

```
entryComponents : [SettingsComponent],
```

So your file should like something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule
  ],
  entryComponents : [SettingsComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```